# Can't find URI from DB2 Service Credentials

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

Hi I'm having this problem when I try to do the following steps.

```
# Remember the connection string is of the format:
# %sql ibm_db_sa://my-username:my-password@hostname:port/BLUDB?security=SSL
# Enter the connection string for your Db2 on Cloud database instance below
# i.e. copy after db2:// from the URI string in Service Credentials of your Db2 instance. Remove the double quotes at the end.
```

Only place where I see **db2://** is below

*"db2://jgd26xxx:ji0BxxxpoZj4zDMA@125fxxx1-xxxx-46f9-9399-c8177b21803b.c1ogj3sd0tgtu0lqde00.databases.appdomain.cloud:30426/bludb?authSource=admin&replicaSet=replset"*

So when I enter that after **%sql ibm_db_sa://** as follows nothing happens. I feel that this is not the correct connection string.

*%sql ibm_db_sa://jgd26xxx:ji0BxxxxZj4xxxA@125xxx61-xxxx-46f9-9399-c8177b21803b.c1ogj3sd0tgtu0lqde00.databases.appdomain.cloud:30426/bludb?authSource=admin&replicaSet=replset*

How do I enter the connection string?

Comment: Are those real credentials? Add more details on what environment you are using. What is the error message?

Comment: are you using db2 hosted on IBM cloud?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `db2 hosted on ibm cloud`, then you can go to your dashboard at `cloud.ibm.com`, select the tab under Resource summary on the main page that says `Services and software`. Once you do that, select your `db2` instance. Once it brings you to the next page, select `service credentials` from the left nav bar. If you dont have a service cred, create one. If you do, select it, and you'll have to do a bit of string building. Find the username by searching for `username` (using command f or what have you), and do the same for the `password`. Do the same for hostname,port, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

URI is not a specific line that you can copy/paste from service credentials.
You have to copy them individually (name/password/...) from service credentials with format as  per line 2 of your question.
I have pasted my format in a text file  so that don't have to do it again and again from service credentials.

Answer (score 0):

you will have your credentials. from there you can copy and paste each data .
username in place of *my-username*,
password in place of *my-password*,
hostname in place of *hostname*,
port in place of *port*,

in given format
`%sql ibm_db_sa`://`my-username`:`my-password`@`hostname`:`port`/ `BLUDB?security=SSL`

Answer (score -1):

What i did is from service credential of db2 of the ibm console, save the whole credential into the text doc. then i drag it just after db2// of the long characteristics which contain the username password and stuff like that n put it on the new cell of the note book just below the required cell and finally merge the two cells together and removed the double quote at the end. this work for me.